# Unit Test Finishes before Thread.Sleep time

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

My program is a simple timer (it's a Pomodoro Timer). I'm trying to incorporate unit testing into my personal projects.

I run my tests on each timer class' run() method and assert that the endTime - startTime is within 1 second of how long I set the timer.

MyTimer.run() invokes Thread.sleep(timerMilliseconds).

My unit tests pass in less time than each timer is set for.

How is this possible?

Eg. Rest is set to 5 seconds, unit test passes in < 1ms

```
[TestMethod]
        public void testRun () {
            TimeSpan fiveSeconds = new TimeSpan(5000);
            Rest rest = new Rest(fiveSeconds, null);
            TimeSpan startTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
            try {
                rest.run();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Assert.Fail(e.ToString());
            }

            Assert.AreEqual(startTime.Add(fiveSeconds).TotalMilliseconds, DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds, 1000 , "Actual sleep time not expected");
        }


 public class Rest : Session {

        private TimeSpan timeSpan;

        public override void run () {
            Thread.Sleep(base.getTimer().Milliseconds); **//SOLVED: SHOULD READ base.getTimer().TotalMilliseconds**
        }

        public Rest (TimeSpan timeSpan, Cycle cycle) : base(timeSpan, cycle) {
            this.timeSpan = timeSpan;
        }
    }


 public abstract class Session {
        private readonly TimeSpan timer;
        protected Cycle cycle;

        public TimeSpan getTimer () {
            return this.Timer;
        }

        protected Session (TimeSpan minutes, Cycle cycle) {
            this.timer = minutes;
            this.cycle = cycle;
        }

        public abstract void run ();
    }
```

Comment: 'now' is a poor name for that variable. By the time you are using it it is no longer 'now'. startTime would be less confusing.

Comment: What is `base.getMinutes()` returning? 5 seconds would produce 0 minutes, the `Milliseconds` of which would also be 0, so I'm thinking this is running without waiting at all.

Comment: @Cory It's a poorly named variable. base.getMinutes() returns a TimeSpan that is initialized on creation, not the TimeSpan.Minutes attribute. I should refactor my variable names before posting for help. Sorry

Comment: What is "Rest"? I thought it was a .Net type but apparently not. Since it is the code that is misbehaving it is *kind* of important to be clear what it actually is.

Comment: @DougClark: No problem, just curious. Another thing is you might was to allow for some tolerance in your assertion, say 10-20 milliseconds. I don't know if it will ever exactly match to the millisecond, but it would probably be close.

Comment: @Bruce Rest extends my base Timer class.

Comment: @Cory Right, that's the third argument in Assert.AreEqual, a 1 second tolerance.

Comment: Note that attempting to provide [MCVE] would likely have solved the problem without posting here... But it also would deprive you from 10 rep-points... Not really sure if anyone can handle such choice in favor of solving themselves...

Comment: Next time be sure to post all of the code, so as to avoid wasting people's time. And, try using a debugger. Stepping through the run() call would have made the problem obvious.

Learning how to solve your own problems is what will make you a useful developer. This one should have been easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic problem is this:

```
public override void run () {
    Thread.Sleep(base.getTimer().Milliseconds);
}
```

You want to sleep for [`TotalMilliseconds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds.aspx), not [`Milliseconds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.milliseconds.aspx) (the `Milliseconds` component of the `TimeSpan` - 0 in this case).

That said, speaking more broadly, you just don't want to unit test a method that calls `Thread.Sleep`, especially not to test the duration of the call. That test will take a long time, be brittle and approximative; 3 properties you absolutely want to avoid in unit tests. To make this code testable, you'd need to abstract the call to `Thread.Sleep` behind some interface that you can then mock in your unit tests (see *dependency injection*). Your unit test could have then verified that the value passed to Sleep() was what you expected, and you would have caught this bug without all the problems that testing a real call to `Thread.Sleep` will cause.

Comment: Ha! Right under my nose, per usual. And I definitely plan on implementing others solutions i found on stackoverflow that test methods that invoke thread sleep. This was just to be sure I had the basic flow right. Thanks!